# How to mask vectors in reduce_XXX Tensorflow operations?

Tags: tensorflow

Let `X` be some tensor whose first dimension is unknown (the batch size) and second and third dimensions are known, `n,m`. Let `Y` be a tensor of the same dimensions which is a mask of `X`, i.e. for each sample in the batch it contains `1` where `X[b,n,m]` contains true values and `0` where it is just padding.

I would like to run summary operations on the rows / columns of `X`, subject to the mask. I.e., If some row `n` of some sample of `X` contains zeros from some point `n_0` on, I wouldn't like the calculation to include it.

While I can resolve this manually for operations such as `reduce_mean` or `reduce_min`, I can't use `reduce_prod` for instance if the matrix is padded by zero...

Is there a way to perform `reduce_XXX` type Tensorflow operations using a vector mask?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use dynamic partition to separate your data into two tensors using mask values

```
data = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3])
mask = tf.cast(data>0, tf.int32)
bad_data, good_data = tf.dynamic_partition(data, mask, 2)
sess.run(tf.reduce_prod(good_data))
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that tf.dynamic_partition, as well as tf.boolean_mask flattens the vector in the other dimensions (for example in the batch_size). It cannot do otherwise since tensors has to be "alligned boxes" but you usually want to run reduce_XXX to every sample separately. Can you fix it?

Comment: a few ops only support flat tensors, the solution typically needs some kind of combination of reshaping, applying some operations, and reshaping back